# InfluxDB and Grafana: InfluxDB Error: Bad Request | Docker

Tags: docker, grafana, influxdb, grafana-templating, influxdb-2

I am trying to connect Grafana with InfluxDB, but it throws

InfluxDB Error: Bad Request

Both i have in docker, and I am using this [tutorial](https://linuxbaya.blogspot.com/2020/11/sensor-data-visualization-using-mqtt-and-grafana.html) where he wrote download and run

```
docker pull influxdb

docker run \
-d \
--name influxdb \
-p 8086:8086 \
-e INFLUXDB_DB=sensordata \
-e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=root \
-e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=toor \
-e INFLUXDB_HTTP_AUTH_ENABLED=true \
influxdb
```

and about Grafana

```
docker pull grafana/grafana

docker run -d --name=grafana -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana
```

In Grafana setting I wrote all as were show in tutorial

url: http://10.0.1.76:8086/

database: sensordata

user: root

passwd: toor

Could please somebody help me with this ?  Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the tutorial you pointed out, is using influxdb version prior to 2.0

Try
docker pull influxdb:1.8.4-alpine

and use this image to start your influxdb container and it should work.

Thanks